# Can't deploy application to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku

Good people, please help.

Why my files didn't add after command "git add . " ?

I can't push files, I get error:

```
       $ git push heroku master
         Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the
        list of known hosts.
        Counting objects: 2, done.
        Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 200 bytes, done.
        Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
        -----> Heroku receiving push
        !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

        To git@heroku.com:simple-rain-7316.git
        ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
        error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:simple-rain-7316.git'
```

or recommend me another server for Rails on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your git remote is using the ssh protocol.

First, you need to create an ssh key pair (ssh-keygen) then login to heroku (heroku login), upload your public key to heroku (heroku keys:add) then try pushing again.

Comment: thanks. and one more question: how I can push if it doesn't ADD anything ? I should delete history or something like that?

Comment: sorry, I worry a lot... Repeat: "... add anything"

Comment: "git add" command doesn't have anything to do with the error you were getting. "git add ." will always add whatever new file you created, except those filtered in .gitignore 

If you did "git add ." and pushed successfully and still don't see any effect when you refresh, you may have to restart your server with "heroku restart"